# GitHub "There was an error committing your changes: File could not be edited"

Tags: image, github, directory

I'm trying to create an images folder for github portfolio. When trying to create a folder I keep getting this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucA16.png)

I tried everything I saw on StackOverflow, Youtube, Github community, etc. And still can't seem to solve this.